# why does a react library cause a blank page on server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

react-photo-collage working on localhost, but on server, just renders a blank page, after removing the part with collage from my code it renders normal.

Weird was it was working all fine yesterday.

Github : [repository](https://github.com/reha350/KUDBosancica)
Problem lies in the events.js

Comment: is there an error in the console?

Comment: It seems to work fine, here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-lake-h1nfg?file=/src/App.js) and the result: https://h1nfg.csb.app/events

Comment: Live : https://www.kudbosancica.de/events